# Python 3- Group by for binned rows

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, group-by

I have a df called exp with the following columns:

```
| category | p_value | score |
| tennis   |  0.45   |  432  |
| soccer   |  0.88   |  46   |
```

My goal is to bin all the scores per p value and create an accumulative plot that is grouped by category.

I managed to create the bin using the following:

```
# find the p_value bin, each row belongs to
# 0 is underflow, len(edges) is overflow bin
exp['bin'] = np.digitize(exp['p value'], bins=bin_edges)

# get the number of UBI per p_value bin
score_per_bin = exp.groupby('bin')['score'].sum()
```

And than managed to plot it:
 not every bin might be filled, so we will use pandas index

```
binned = pd.DataFrame({
    'center': bin_center,
    'width': bin_width,
    'score': np.zeros(len(bin_center))
}, index=np.arange(1, len(bin_edges)))

binned['score'] = score_per_bin


plt.step(
    binned['center'],
    binned['score'].cumsum(),
    where='mid',
)
plt.xlabel('p-value')
plt.ylabel('score')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I get a plot with 1 line while I need a line per category.
My question is - how do I keep the category and plot it?

Thank you

Comment: @black_fm maybe you can help?